# Best way to start a python app/script/file with another python script so that it doesn't hold up the file that runs it

Tags: python, debugging, tkinter, interface, ide

I am working on a python editor/ide and I have been using `os.startfile(file_path)` to run the files but because this is like starting them using python.exe the console closes as soon as the file finishes running or it runs into an error.

I am looking for a method of running python files that has them behaving normally (like ran with idle/visual studio code), but the console output still being visible after it finishes running or crashes so I can see the error messages and the print() output.

This method can't hold up the python script that started it so that the tkinter interface I am using doesn't freeze.

Comment: if you want the console to keep open and tkinter not freeze, open the console in a separate thread than the one used by tkinter and put an `input()` at the end of the code executed by the console, so it doesn't automatically close when finished.

Comment: `os.startfile()` is absolutely inappropriate to run a Python file. It opens the file with the default application, which for security reasons should not be the Python interpreter directly. Check the [`subprocess`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html) module to run programms or make the code you are calling a function and run it in a [thread](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html).